# Inserting Celery tasks directly into Redis

Tags: redis, celery

I have an Erlang system.  I want this system to be able to trigger Celery tasks on another, Python-based system.  They share the same host, and Celery is using Redis as its broker.

Is it possible to insert tasks for Celery directly into Redis (in my case, from Erlang), instead of using a Celery API?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can insert tasks directly into redis or whatever backend you are using with celery.

You'll have to match the celery serialization format (which is in JSON by default) and figure out which keys it is inserting to. The key structure used isn't clearly documented, but [this part](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/backends/redis.py) of the source code is a good place to start.

You can also use the redis [`monitor`](https://redis.io/commands/monitor) command to watch which keys celery uses in real time.

Answer (score 0):

According to the task message [definition](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/internals/protocol.html#task-messages) from the Celery docs, the body of the message has the following format (for version 5.2):

```
body = (
    object[] args,
    Mapping kwargs,
    Mapping embed {
        'callbacks': Signature[] callbacks,
        'errbacks': Signature[] errbacks,
        'chain': Signature[] chain,
        'chord': Signature chord_callback,
    }
)
```

Therefore, to trigger a task you should put a message with a body like this to your Celery backend's queue (represented as a Python data structure):

```python
[
    ['arg1', 'arg2'],  # positional arguments for the task
    {'kwarg1': 'val1', 'kwarg2': 'val2'},  # keyword arguments for the task
    {'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'chain': None, 'chord': None}
]
```